# Laravel - how to deal with controller extends another controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, user-controls

I'm having Laravel app that have two controllers `UserController` an `AdminController` , ofcourse **Admin** have more credentials than user and here comes my question:

I want **User** to be able to:

1. fetch and view account
2. fetch and view mail

and **Admin** to be able to:

1. fetch and view account
2. fetch and view mail
3. manage account
4. manage mail

obviously there is redundant in the **fetching and viewing** functionality for both, so **I tried** to creating two controllers. the `AdminController` **extends** `UserController`:

`UserController`:

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\Account;
use App\Mail;


class UserController extends Controller
{
        /*******************
         * Helper functions
         * retrieving data
         ***/

        //retrieving data from database
        protected function getaccount($userId){
            //fetch data from database
        }
        protected function getmail($userId){
            //fetch mail from database
        }

        /*******************
         *other controller functions
         ***/
 }
```

`AdminController`:

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\Account;
use App\Mail;


class AdminController extends Controller, UserController
{
        /*******************
         * Helper functions
         * retrieving data
         ***/

        //retrieving data from database
        protected function manageaccount($userId){
            //manage
        }
        protected function managemail($userId){
            //manage
        }

        /*******************
         *other controller functions
         ***/
 }
```

**how** can I use the **fetching and viewing** functions of `UserController` in `AdminController`?

Comment: Instead prepare an interface and use implements along with DI

Comment: I'm new, so could you explain more if you have time ?

Comment: do you mean using **Trait** ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put your `getaccount` and `getmail` methods on your `User` model class.

Comment: can you explain to me why your approach is better ? more secure?